# How can i get the Differential ID in Phabricator from a branch

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I have made a commit on a particular branch and then I made a Differential patch with Arcanist (executing `arc diff`).

Now I forget the differential ID of this particular Differential. I want to get it back. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to that branch and use the command `arc which`, it should tell you the Diff.  Also, if you used `arc diff` to make the differential, the commit message of that commit should have been updated with a URL to the Diff.

Comment: Here's the full command: `arc which | grep -E "D[0-9]+" -o`. Use with caution.